Is there any way to land transactions within 1-2 blocks without relying on an expensive SWQoS provider?
I am executing swaps on pumpfun and raydium (using typescript). I am using a dedicated paid node, sending my transaction using sendRawTransaction() and then using getTransaction() with the tx signature to fetch "confirmed" transaction. However, that is still taking around 5-6s to complete the entire transaction flow. How do I land the transactions within 1-2 blocks?

Unfortunately, it isn't really possible without SWQoS. You might do a bit better if you use a TPU client and send transactions directly to the leader rather than using RPC, but they can also drop your transaction more easily.
